# Using Parameters in SSRS with LIKE operator

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create a report that has a list of various product groups as parameters. When selecting each group, a list of those related products should appear. I am currently getting a blank table.

[image: query]

The results for this product group display when i execute the query.

I have the list of parameters and values as follows:

[image: parameters]

i'm struggling to see where I have gone wrong, when i preview the report, I can select each parameter, but get an empty table in the report. I expect the way I have given each parameter a value may be the problem, but cannot figure it out.

This is the query in the report.

```
DECLARE @ProductCode VARCHAR(12)

SELECT STRC_CODE, STRC_DESC FROM DeFactoUser.F_ST_Products
WHERE STRC_CODE LIKE @ProductCode
```

I am using Visual Studio Data Tools 2012 to build the report.

If anyone could give me a clue, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you need to surround your parameter values with single quotes?

Comment: It doesn't work without the quotes. I thought the quotes and wildcard would be necessary to allow the LIKE operator to work.

Comment: "It does'nt work " - what do you mean exactly?

Comment: The report is still empty, no results are visible.

Comment: It seems that you are not mapping the parameter but declaring it on the SQL

Comment: @Jayvee could you elaborate please?

Comment: remove the `DECLARE @ProductCode VARCHAR(12)` from your report query.  When you put @ in front of a word, SSRS will automatically treat it as a parameter, no need to declare it

Comment: @JamieD77 I have removed the DECLARE line from the query in the report, that was only used when executing the query with a given value in management studio.

Comment: @NealS without the Declare and the single quotes it should work

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It doesn't work without the quotes. I thought the quotes and wildcard
>   would be necessary to allow the LIKE operator to work.

First of all you **don't need to use quotes**, I tried to reproduce it right now and it works without quotes:
[image]

Second, the query that SSRS sends to server looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select model
from [dbo].[cars]
where model like @car',N'@car nvarchar(3)',@car=N'ca%'
```

So the only thing it changes respect to your code is parameter type, it always declares it as unicode, i.e. nvarchar(...), so maybe it make sense to try in SSMS your code with parameter type changed to `nvarchar(12)`:

```
declare ProductCode nvarchar(5) = N'PA.A%'
```

Try to execute it in SSMS and see if it returns smth or not

Comment: The only thing I can think about in this case: do you connect to the right server and right database? I had no problem at all to make it work and I use the same SSRS 2012, so I exclude any bug within it

Comment: Can you use SQL Server profiler to monitor what exaclty is sent to your server?

Comment: I don't understand this line in your code..... `where model like @car',N'@car nvarchar(3)',@car=N'ca%'` How does that transfer to what I am trying to do?

Comment: @NealS What line?

Comment: Another thing can be row-level security. Do you execute your report under the same win user hpp\neals or maybe reporting is configured to use another (not windows) user? What is your **F_ST_Products**? Is it a table or a view?

Comment: Security shouldn't be an issue.  It is a table.

Comment: >>>I don't understand this line in your code..... where model like @car',N'@car nvarchar(3)',@car=N'ca%' How does that transfer to what I am trying to do?<<< Since I have no your table I used mine, dbo.cars, to make a condition similar to yours and then I used Profiler to see what is sent to server (if it's adding additional quotes?. It's just an imitation of your report using MY table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154700/discussion-between-neals-and-sepupic).

Comment: SSRS gets your parameter value, quotes it by itself (so you need not to quote it in parameter dialog), and sends to server dynamic sql like what I posted above, so it executes parameterized query. That's all